# How do I access settings in WhatsApp on Samsung Galaxy Note 3?

Tags: samsung, whatsapp-messenger

I don't see the ellipses icon ("...") in the top-right corner of the screen on my Samsung Galaxy Note 3. Without it, how can I get to the Settings screen in WhatsApp?

Comment: Not clear question.

Comment: Seems your device has physical menu button. The "overflow" menu button won't be shown if there is physical menu button. [This article](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2475071/smartphones-hands-on-7-silly-things-about-the-galaxy-note-3.html) somewhat explains your "issue".

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, try pressing the hardware "Menu" button:

[[image: menu button]

<sub>click for larger image</sub>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJUV9.jpg)

On latest Android versions the overflow (ellipses) button is hidden in apps on phones with a physical Menu button.